# django-viewflow get task assign url for the next step?

Tags: django-viewflow

I have a typical workflow like below:

```
Start -> Notify -> Task -> End
```

Within the Notify step which sends out an email to someone need to perform the task, I want to include the url that goes directly to the "Task" assign page, is it possible?

My problem is, during the Notify step I don't think the Task step has been created in database yet, so cannot generate the url.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the answer, posting the code to generate the assign url:

```py
def handler(self, activation):
    process = activation.process
    path = reverse('viewflow:connect:new_request/flow/newrequest:{}__assign'.format(activation.flow_task.name), args=[process.pk, activation.task.pk])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add it as flow.View(...).[onCreate handler](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/nodes/view.py#L224)

```
class MyFlow(Flow):
    approve = flow.View(...).OnCreate(this.on_approve_created)

    def on_approve_created(self, activation):
        if activation.task.owner:
            send_mail(
                'View task assigned to you','Here is the message.',
                'from@example.com', [activation.task.owner.email]
             )
```